# How to show the timeline at the top of a timevis

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

Is it possible to show the time/date at the top of a timevis (and not at the bottom) ?

```
timevis(
    data.frame(id = 1:2,
         content = c("one", "two"),
         start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12"))
  )
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `timevis` has an argument called `options` to customize the timeline. See [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options) for all possible configuration options.

```
timevis(
  data = data.frame(
    id = 1:2,
    content = c("one", "two"),
    start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12")
  ),
  options = list(orientation = "top")
)
```

[image]